# learnyounode: #3 My First I/O

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell, npm, visual-studio-code

I am trying this in **Visual Studio Code on Windows 10** with **powershell.exe** as Terminal.

After many failures, I peaked in the internet to find its solution.

Here's the solution that I have got from the internet:

```
var fs = require('fs');
       
var contents = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2]);
var lines = contents.toString().split('\n').length - 1;
console.log(lines);
```

I saved it in a file, myFirstIO.js. However, I tried running it on **PowerShell**, I received the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\aps12\Desktop\Test\lyn> node myFirstIO.js
fs.js:640
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer
    at TypeError (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:508:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aps12\Desktop\Test\lyn\myFirstIO.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
```

But when typed,

```
PS C:\Users\aps12\Desktop\Test\lyn> learnyounode verify myFirstIO.js
```

Surprisingly,  solution got passed.

```
 # PASS Your solution to MY FIRST I/O! passed!
```

I wonder why the solution get passed even when it was not running.
Also, why the solution was not running? What is the mistake I have made there?
PS: I have already cleared first two modules of **learnyounode** without any failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this program using `node myFirstIO.js` it will throw an error, because it expects a file as second argument

```
/*
on this line, file being read using readFileSync and saving it to a
contents variable
*/
var contents = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2]);
```

If you notice the error `TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer`, it expecting a file path string or file stream as second argument.

When you are running this program with learnyounode, they implicitly running it with a file, you can also test this by running it like `node myFirstIO.js textfile.txt` 
Note, file path must be valid.

If you run this program like  `node myFirstIO.js "Hello World"` it won't work, as it expects a file path or stream not a string. Hope this helps you understand this issue.

Answer (score 0):

*process.argv* returns all arguments given in command line.

When you do `> node myFirstIO.js`, you're passing these arguments to process.argv:

`['node', 'myFirstIO.js']`

... It threw an error cuz you were asking for the third argument (**process.argv[2]**), which you didn't pass in the command line.

*Read about **process.argv** [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv).*

Now, for learnyounode, either I assume you passed the third argument when you used:

`> learnyounode verify myFirstIO.js`

using the JS file as third argument; or *learnyounode* is **buggy**.

Comment: Even when I used something like this:
`> node myFirstIO.js "Hello World"`
It still, showed the same error.

Comment: From your code's point of view, the third argument has to be a file name. It could be a relative path from the folder, or an absolute path. 

It must be *path* + *file.extension*.

Say, if your code only this line: 


```console.log(process.argv[2])```


this 

```> node myFirstIO.js "hello world"``` should work, but since you're working with the FS module, it requires the path of a file passed as an argument.